# comparing nsmutablearray and adding new objects

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios6, merge, nsmutablearray

```
NSMutableArray *a1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *a2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

a1 having following objects name, number;
a2 having following objects id,gender,age,location,number;

By comparing number I have to merge only if number matching. While merging I need results like as follows
Name , number,id,gender,age,location;

Comment: and these objects (stored in array) are nsdictionary or data classes?

Comment: not sure what you mean by merging.

Comment: Andrey. That objects are in nsmutablearray.

Comment: Andrey. That objects are in nsmutablearray. Example. a1 is nsmutablearray with elements are index1 name="a"; number=123;  index2 name="b";number=666;likewise also a2 nsmutablearray with elements are index1 number=12354; id=1;gender="m";age=23;location="Los Angeles"; index2 number=567;id=2;gender="m";age=45;location="Texas"; index3 number=666;id=3;gender="f";age=24;location="New York";  a1 nsmutablearray index2 number matching with a2 nsmutablearray index3 number. So I am expecting result as a3 nsmutablearray with element are name="b";number=666;id=3;gender="f";age=24;location="New York";